# Query works but when put it in stored procedure doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I test below query and works properly

```
select * from tbl where userName in ('A','B','C')
```

but when I create a stored procedure and pass the parameter to it doesn't work (the parameter is correct)

```
SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("exec example @userName",...
sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", "'A','B','C'");
...

// Stored Procedure
create procedure example 
    @users varchar(100)
as
    select * from tbl where userName in ('@users')
```

Comment: are you sure this query worked? `select * from tbl where userName in ('A,B,C')`? isn't it `...('A','B','C')`

Comment: Are you really passing in a single string as a comma-separated list `('A,B,C')`? Or are you passing in 3 separate strings `('A', 'B', 'C')`?  They will be treated different and need to be handled different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put the argument in quotes.

However, just having:

```
select * from tbl where userName in (@users)
```

Won't work either as then you are trying to use the `in` function on a string that happens to represent a list of elements.

You'll need to convert the string to an array and then use that in the select statement:

The MSDN has an [example function for doing this](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SQLExamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=StringArrayInput):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split 
   (  @Delimiter varchar(5), 
      @List      varchar(8000)
   ) 
   RETURNS @TableOfValues table 
      (  RowID   smallint IDENTITY(1,1), 
         [Value] varchar(50) 
      ) 
AS 
   BEGIN
      DECLARE @LenString int 

      WHILE len( @List ) > 0 
         BEGIN 
            SELECT @LenString = 
               (CASE charindex( @Delimiter, @List ) 
                   WHEN 0 THEN len( @List ) 
                   ELSE ( charindex( @Delimiter, @List ) -1 )
                END
               ) 

            INSERT INTO @TableOfValues 
               SELECT substring( @List, 1, @LenString )

            SELECT @List = 
               (CASE ( len( @List ) - @LenString ) 
                   WHEN 0 THEN '' 
                   ELSE right( @List, len( @List ) - @LenString - 1 ) 
                END
               ) 
         END
      RETURN 
    END
```

Then use it like this:

```
select * from tbl where userName in (SELECT * FROM dbo.Split( ',', @users ))
```

Answer (score 1):

"in" queries are notoriously hard to parameterise. Firstly, don't put the parameter in quotes - then it isn't a parameter: it is a character literal. But: you also can't *just* use a single parameter - as that would be searching for a single value that simply has quotes and commas in - not what you intended.

There are various approaches here; for example using a "split" function at the server and inner joining to that result. However, some tools also help. For example, "dapper" allows a syntax tweak:

```
var names = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };

var users = connection.Query<User>(
    "select * from users where name in @names",
    new { names }).ToList();
```

The library expands this into a correct "in" query using multiple parameters.